# confirm modal jquery bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html

I have this code:

clicking in this link:

```
   <td><?php echo anchor("atendimento/delete/{$record->id}", 'Excluir', ['class'=>'btn btn-danger', 
                            'name' => 'delete', 'id' => 'anchordelete']); ?></td>
```

Show a modal with two buttons `Sim` and `Nao`, where `Sim` means Yes and `Nao` means No. If i click in `Sim` need to delete the data from DB.

```
<div class="modal fade" role="dialog" id="myModal">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
         <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content" >
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Atenção</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p id="confirm-message"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="confirm">Sim</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" id="cancel">Não</button>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    $("a[name='delete']").on('click', function(e){

        $("#confirm-message").html("Confirma a EXCLUSÃO do registro?");
        $('#myModal').modal("show");

        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('#confirm').on('click', function(){

            $("a[name='delete']").trigger('click');
            $("a[name='delete']").removeAttr("name");

            $('#myModal').modal("hide");
    });

});
```

Not working, when i click in `Nao`, the modal close but if i click in `Sim`, nothing happened.

edit:

here's my php loop

```
 <?php if(count($records)){ ?>

                    <?php foreach($records as $record) {?>
                        <tr>
                          <td><?php echo $record->data; ?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $record->assunto; ?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $record->responsavel; ?></td>

                          <td><?php echo anchor("atendimento/edit/{$record->id}", 'Atualizar', ['class'=>'btn btn-success']); ?> </td>
                          <td><?php echo anchor("atendimento/delete/{$record->id}", 'Excluir', ['class'=>'btn btn-danger', 
                            'name' => 'delete', 'id' => 'anchordelete']); ?></td>

                        </tr>
                    <?php }?>
               <?php } ?>
```

Comment: do you have multiple `#anchordelete`? did you try `$("#anchordelete").trigger('click')` ?

Comment: you're right in one thing... i have multiple id with same name.. now i've edited.. but same problem

Comment: you need to find the delete button based on the confirm button

Comment: i'm sorry... what do you mean... my confirm button its a button in the modal.. when i click.. need to do the link action (delete)

Comment: if you have multiple delete buttons how do you know which to click?

Comment: you're right... now i dont know.. because i'm trying with only one data... how do i control that?

Comment: where is you delete button relative to your confirm button?

Comment: in your page man in your page the link is above the confirm link, below it where?

Comment: its inside php loop.. im gettin records from DB and displaying in html table dinamically

Comment: can you post the loop as well in the question?

Comment: already done right now

Comment: so the modal is not in the loop, yes?

Comment: outside the loop...

Comment: how do you pass the content of a row to the modal to edit the row?

Comment: i'm not passing the content to a modal for edit.. i'm just need use the modal for delete...

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use window.location to go to the delete page, pass the url on click to the modal using a data attribute

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    $("a[name='delete']").on('click', function(e){

        $("#confirm-message").html("Confirma a EXCLUSÃO do registro?");
        $('#myModal').attr('data-url',$(this).attr('href'));
        $('#myModal').modal("show");

        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('#confirm').on('click', function(){
          window.location = $(this).closest('#myModal').attr('data-url')
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$("#anchordelete")[0].click();
```

jQuery's `.click()` will try and add a click handler, and not actually click on the element. Using `[0]` will refer to the first element, and click it.